# My TableViewCell isn't deleting from Core Data, reappears when tableview is brought back into view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, singleton

I have a CoreDataManager class that is responsible for creating codes and descriptions to be displayed in a TableView and also for adding additional rows to the Tableview to persist in Core Data. When I add new rows they appear in the Tableview exactly as they're supposed to and when I swipe to delete them they disappear as they should, but when I leave the TableView and come back the rows I just deleted are still there. I'll post some of the CoreDataManager class and the TableView class.

CoreDataManager.h -

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface CoreDataManager : NSObject

@property (readonly, strong) NSPersistentContainer *persistentContainer;

- (void)saveContext;

-(BOOL)deleteCode:(NSString*)name description:(NSString*)desc;

+(CoreDataManager*)sharedInstance;

-(void)storeListFirstTime; //This will save your initial list of content

-(NSArray*)fetchAllRecords;//get All the record from your table

-(BOOL)saveNewCode:(NSString*)codeName description:(NSString*)codeDesc;

@end
```

CoreDataManager.m -

```
#import "CoreDataManager.h"
#import "UsefulCodes+CoreDataClass.h"

@implementation CoreDataManager

+(CoreDataManager*)sharedInstance {
    static CoreDataManager *sharedObject;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedObject = [[CoreDataManager alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedObject;
}

//THIS HOLDS ALL THE INITIAL CODES AND DESCRIPTIONS IN TABLEVIEW AND ARE NOT TO BE REMOVED
-(void)storeListFirstTime {

    NSArray* presetList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"AS",
                                               @"BCNU",
                                               @"CL",
                                               @"CT",
                                               @"CUL",
                                               @"K",
                                               @"QSL",
                                               @"QSL?",
                                               @"QRX?",
                                               @"QRV",
                                               @"QRV?",
                                               @"QTH",
                                               @"QTH?",
                                               @"R",
                                               @"SN",
                                               @"SOS",
                                               @"73",
                                               @"88",
                                               nil];


    NSArray* codeDescArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Wait",
                                                  @"Be seeing You",
                                                  @"Going off air",
                                                  @"Start Copying",
                                                  @"See you later",
                                                  @"Over",
                                                  @"I acknowledge receipt",
                                                  @"Do you acknowledge",
                                                  @"Should I wait",
                                                  @"Ready to copy",
                                                  @"Are you ready to copy?",
                                                  @"My location is ...",
                                                  @"What is your location?",
                                                  @"Roger",
                                                  @"Understood",
                                                  @"Distress message",
                                                  @"Best regards",
                                                  @"Love and kisses",
                                                  nil];

//Saves the initial list of items
for(int i = 0; i < presetList.count; i++) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self context];
        UsefulCodes *codeObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UsefulCodes"
                                                           inManagedObjectContext:context];
        codeObj.codeName = [presetList objectAtIndex:i];
        codeObj.codeDescription = [codeDescArray objectAtIndex:i];
    }
    [self saveContext];
}

-(NSArray*)fetchAllRecords {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self context];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"UsefulCodes"];
    NSArray *records = [context executeFetchRequest:request
                                          error:&error];

    if(error == nil && records.count > 0) {
        return [records copy];
    }
    else {
        //Handle error by returning new array
        return [NSArray new];
    }
}

//RESPONSIBLE FOR SAVING NEW CODE AND ADDING TO TABLEVIEW

-(BOOL)saveNewCode:(NSString*)codeName description:(NSString*)codeDesc {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self context];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"UsefulCodes"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"codeName = %@", codeName];
    request.predicate = predicate;

    NSArray *records = [context executeFetchRequest:request
                                          error:&error];

    if(error == nil && records.count > 0) {
        UsefulCodes *code = [records firstObject];

        //Updating description
        code.codeDescription = codeDesc;
    }
    else {//Add new code Object to table
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self context];
        UsefulCodes *codeObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UsefulCodes"
                                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
        codeObj.codeName = codeName;
        codeObj.codeDescription = codeDesc;
    }

    //Save changes
    if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {
        //Saved successfully
        return true;
    }
    else {
        //handle error
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

/*  Boiler plate Core Data Stack set up done here  */

#pragma mark - Core Data Saving support

- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }
}

-(NSManagedObjectContext*)context {
    return self.persistentContainer.viewContext;
}

@end
```

I believe the method "fetchAllRecords" is the culprit for the tableview returning the deleted objects again as you will see in my TableViewController class below.

MCTableViewController.h -

```
@interface MCTableViewController :     UITableViewController<addNewCellData> {
    __weak id selectDataDelegate;
    //CUSTOM DELEGATE RESPONSIBLE FOR HANDLING NEW CODE AND DESCRIPTION INPUT AND PASSING INTO TABLEVIEW
}

@property (readonly, strong) NSPersistentContainer *persistentContainer;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *presetList;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *codeDescArray;
@property(nonatomic,weak)id<sendDataProtocol> selectedDataDelegate;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UILabel *codeTitle;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UILabel *codeDesc;
```

MCTableViewController.m -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Declare new NSMutableArray in the two properties below
    self.presetList = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.codeDescArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    //Loading data from DB
    [self reloadDataset];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.presetList count];
}

//THIS IS WHERE EDITING HAPPENS AND WHERE I'M TRYING TO REMOVE THE CORE DATA OBJECT FROM THE TABLEVIEW

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [self.presetList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [self.context deleteObject:selectedObject];
        [self.context save:nil];

        [self.presetList removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

//DATA IS RECEIVED FROM OTHER VIEW HERE AND SAVED TO THE TABLEVIEW
#pragma mark - Delegate for receiving new data
- (void)sendDataToTableView:(NSString*)code codeDesc:(NSString*)desc {

    NSString *codes = code;
    NSString *descriptions = desc;

    [self.presetList addObject:codes];
    [self.codeDescArray addObject:descriptions];

    //Adding new record OR
    //If codeName is same, updating description in database
    [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] saveNewCode:codes description:descriptions]; 

    [self reloadDataset];
}

//FINALLY...

#pragma mark - Reloading table data from database
-(void)reloadDataset {

    NSArray *array = [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] fetchAllRecords];

    //Removing all objects from current list
    [self.presetList removeAllObjects];
    [self.codeDescArray removeAllObjects];

    for (UsefulCodes *code in array) {

        //CODENAME & CODEDESCRIPTION ARE ATTRIBUTES OF MY CORE DATA ENTITY USEFULCODES
        [self.presetList addObject: code.codeName];
        [self.codeDescArray addObject: code.codeDescription];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Adding to the tableview and saving these new objects to core data is simple but deleting them has been challenging and I've tried a lot but I just can't get it to work. If you've made it this far I would appreciate some advice on what I'm doing wrong and why the data isn't deleting from Core Data properly.

Comment: It *looks* like you are trying to delete the wrong thing. This line in your code `NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [self.presetList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];` *probably* does not return an actual Managed Object, because when you `reloadDataset` you fill `presetList` with `code.codeName`. Put a breakpoint there and see if `selectedObject` is in fact a valid object.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why none of this was working was because I needed to have access to the entire stored list of items and then choose the specific index that I wanted to delete. To get the complete list of stored items I had to call the singleton I created and get the "fetchAllRecords" method and then store it in array, I then proceeded with deleting the object as usual. Overall the code is pretty straight forward, I'll post the answer to my own problem below.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

         if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

            //GET ALL THE CELLS CURRENTLY STORED
            NSArray *array = [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] fetchAllRecords];
            //GET THE SPECIFIC INDEX OF THE STORED ARRAYS
            NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            [selectedObject.managedObjectContext deleteObject:selectedObject];
            NSError *saveError;
            [selectedObject.managedObjectContext save:&saveError];

            [self.presetList removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
    }
```